# How to convert a language item to another language

Tags: multilingual

I have created some test content in english on the sitecore site that I am working on. But I want the site to be in french, so I want to convert all the english content to french one-on-one and I want to do this without code. So I want to create a french versions with all the field content from the english versions (and thereafter I will remove the english content). I have been looking around the sitecore interface, but can't find anything for this purpose. So what is the easiest way to accomplish?

Comment: You may want to try to use a module from the marketplace named "[Smart Tools - Add Version and Copy Content](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Smart_Tools_Add_Version_and_Copy_Content.aspx?sc_lang=en)." This should allow you to copy the items you want to the language you want via the Sitecore interface.

Comment: What version of Sitecore. You want to convert a single page or you want the whole site in one shot?

Answer (score 5):

Most easy way is to use Sitecore Powershell :

First time you need to add copy from english to french.

For recursive you can try below PowerShell script

```
Get-ChildItem /sitecore/content/home -Recurse  |
  ForEach-Object { Add-ItemLanguage $_ -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "fr-fr" -IfExist Over
```

To delete old items from english you can use:

```
 $path = "master:\sitecore\content\yourpath"
@(Get-Item $path) + (Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse) | Remove-ItemLanguage -Language "en"
```

Answer (score 2):

Without code, there is a manual approach that you can do to copy paste values across.

1. On the item, select the French language version. It should warn you that no versions exists.
2. Create a new version. By default, the fields will be blank.
3. Turn on the 'Translate' button in the ribbon and it will let you see the English and French side-by-side.
4. Copy paste the values.

For added ease, you can enable Raw Values display so you can easily copy over GUIds and the like for select fields and media fields.

Another way, which I haven't tried before, and is incredibly hacky, would be to change all your template fields to be Shared, then create the French versions, then change the fields on the templates back to unshared. Not sure, but it might copy the values over in that scenario?